# Вывод первой строки матрицы через forEach

Tags: javascript

Необходимо вывести первую строку матрицы используя цикл forEach

```
matrix = 
[[7, 2, 7, 2, 8],
[2, 9, 4, 1, 7],
[3, 8, 6, 2, 4],
[2, 5, 2, 9, 1],
[6, 6, 5, 4, 5]];

matrix.forEach(function(item, ind){
    matrix[0].forEach(function(item0, ind0){
        console.log(item0);
    })
    return false;
})
```

Проблема в том, что строка выводится пять раз подряд(знаю, что это происходит из-за кол-ва массивов в массиве), а мне надо один раз вывести. return false не помогает, подскажите где неправ

Comment: Зачем нужен вложенный `forEach`? Уберите первый и все выведется ...

Comment: @MedvedevDev как раз только вложенный тут и нужен, а внешний надо убрать

Comment: на самом деле интересно разобраться с return false и понять, где проблема, а идея о том, что нужно убрать внешний цикл и так очевидна

Comment: @teran, ну, "первый" и есть "внешний ... "вложенный forEach" имелось ввиду, что тут не нужен двойной перебор, достаточно один убрать и убрать очевидно нужно "первый" оставив только тот что внутри.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Проблема в том, что строка выводится пять раз подряд(знаю, что это происходит из-за кол-ва массивов в массиве), а мне надо один раз вывести.

как уже обсудили в комментариях, очевидно, что первый внешний цикл `forEach` тут лишний. Вы видимо хотите его прерватьпосле первой же итерации, вернув `false`

> `return false` не помогает, подскажите где неправ

Однако, возможно, вы путаете `.forEach` с `$.each`, ибо для стандартного метода обхода массивов js [согласно MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) имеет место быть следующее:

> **Примечание**: Не существует способа остановить или прервать цикл `forEach()` кроме как выбрасыванием исключения. Если это требуется, метод `forEach()` неправильный выбор. Используйте обычные циклы.

в то же время для jquery верно следующее:

> We can break the `$.each()` loop at a particular iteration by making the callback function return `false`

Так что не правы вы в том, что стандартный цикл просто нельзя остановив вернув `false` из функции обратного вызова.

Comment: спасибо, буду теперь знать

Answer (score 3):

В комментариях сложно описать, по этому пускай будет ответом ... `return false;` после выполнения вложенного цикла в данной задаче не имеет никакого смысла ... Так же `forEach` нельзя прервать, как скажем `for`, но можно сделать что-то типа такого:

```js
matrix = 
[[7, 2, 7, 2, 8],
[2, 9, 4, 1, 7],
[3, 8, 6, 2, 4],
[2, 5, 2, 9, 1],
[6, 6, 5, 4, 5]];

matrix.forEach(function(item, ind){
  if(ind !== 0) return false;
  
  item.forEach(function(item0, ind0){
      console.log(item0);
  })
})
```

Перебор будет полным, но за счет `if(ind !== 0) return false;` мы просто пропускаем все итерации кроме первой.